# TBannerAd doesn't show ads

Tags: delphi, admob, ads

I've created a new App in Delphi 10.3.3 Community Edition, placed a TBannerAd, aligned it to bottom and I have a Button which loads the Ad (`BannerAd1.AdUnitID:='ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX'; BannerAd1.LoadAd;`). I tried The TBannerAd with the sizes "auto" and "small" but when I click the button on the running App no Ad is shown. Everything I do in my App works, but there are no ads shown. I used a Huawei ALE21 with stock rom (Anndroid 6) and a Samsung SM-A605FN/DS (A6 plus) also with stock rom to test the App. I tried test mode and normal mode, but in both cases there is no ad shown. I don't even get an error and I don't have any email from admob which tells me that it doesn't work... On my old computer (Same Delphi version and same mobile phones) I got ads to work. Now on a fresh installed Windows 10 with nothing more than Delphi and a few normal Apps I can't make an app with ads on it. And I don't use any ad blocking app on my phones. They're both stock rom.
Can anyone give me a hint why I can't display any ads without getting an error?

UPDATE: Google sent me an email a few days later saying my app code should change and the ads are not shown until my app fulfills requirements and some stuff like that.. so I guess the issue was I was trying just to show an ad to test ads are working and there was no real content in my app. After trying it a few weeks later in a real app I was trying to get ads shown in it it worked.. So sorry for asking this question. I just didnt know Google dooesnt show ads on blank apps..

Comment: PS: the admob service in the permissions list is enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the simple answer is that there just are no ads to be shown available.. I get an error 3 code, which means the google ad server has nothing for me to show.. I think I should try other phones/accounts as well to get some ads running

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the BannerAd's alignment to `bottom` and ensure that it has sufficient height. Start with the `small` size of Ad. Use the `OnDidFail` and `OnDidLoad` to debug. In my case I fixed the issue by the alignment and choosing small or medium size of Ad. Couldn't get the `large` or `auto` size to work so I am sticking with `medium`. Also, my `BannerAd.TestMode` is set to `true` as I am using the test ID provided by Google (I suppose you have done the same).

Answer (score 0):

did you already set True on Project > Option > Application > Entitlement List > AdMob Service

Comment: The question says that they have enabled that permission, in the PS at the end of the post. It's been in the question since it was edited on Feb 6, so it was in there when you wrote this answer.